# How to group and calculate monthly average in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group a dataset based on the name and find the monthly average. i.e sum all the values for each name divided by the number of the distinct month for each name.

For example,

```
name    time    values
A   2011-01-17  10
B   2011-02-17  20
A   2011-01-11  10
A   2011-03-17  30
B   2011-02-17  10
```

The expected result is

```
name monthly_avg
A    25 
B    30
```

I have tried

```
data.groupby(['name'])['values'].mean().reset_index(name='Monthly Average')
```

but it gives the output below instead of my desired output above:

```
name    Monthly Average
A      16.666667
B      15.000000
```

Comment: It seems to be giving the correct output. A:50/3 = 16.66; B:30/2 = 15.

Comment: No, For example, all the values of B happens in the same month, so the monthly average should be the sum of the all the values

Comment: What is the `Monthly Average` formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert values to datetimes first, then aggregate `sum` per `name` and months by [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) and last get `mean` per first level `name`:

```
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'])

df = (data.groupby(['name', pd.Grouper(freq='m', key='time')])['values'].sum()
          .groupby(level=0)
          .mean()
          .reset_index(name='Monthly Average'))
print (df)
  name  Monthly Average
0    A               25
1    B               30
```

With months period solution is if change `Grouper` to [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'])

df = (data.groupby(['name', data['time'].dt.to_period('m')])['values']
          .sum()
          .groupby(level=0)
          .mean()
          .reset_index(name='Monthly Average'))
print (df)
  name  Monthly Average
0    A               25
1    B               30
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B'], 'time': ['2011-01-17', '2011-02-1', '2011-01-11', '2011-03-17', '2011-02-17'], 'vals': range(5)})
df['month']=pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.month
a1 = df.groupby('name')['month'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
a2 = df.groupby('name')['vals'].sum()
a2/a1
```

output:
[image]